# Are primitive data types mutable or immutable in java?

Tags: java

Are primitive data types mutable or immutable in java?

```
student{
  int id;
}
```

now student has id as instance member.

```
student st = new Student();
int id = 20;
st.id = id;
id = 30;
```

Does student object get changes? What happens if we use `Integer` wrapper class instead of primitives?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Sometimes practice is better than theory.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037082/are-java-primitives-immutable

Comment: primitive types are obviously immutable, but your `Student` class has ***nothing*** to do with being primitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitive datatypes in Java have no references. When you set

```
st.id = id;
```

you only set the value (20) on the primitive variable st.id. There is no connection between st.id and id.

Otherwise when you use Integer, st.id and id are references.

```
Integer id = new Integer(20);
```

creates and Object in the heap and id is the reference that points to it.

```
st.id = id;
```

copies the reference to st.id. This reference also points to the object (Integer(20)) in the heap.

But a change of

```
id = new Integer(21);
```

doesnt change the value of st.id. It only changes the pointer of id to a different Object in heap.