# In Java, why can we use the String class as if it were a primitive?

Tags: java, string, class

In Java we usually do:

```
Class myObject = new Class();
```

because the `new` keyword returns an address.

But why can we do this?:

```
String myString = "Hello";
```

as if `String` were a primitive?

I asked this to my teacher and he replied that it is because what is in quotes is equivalent to an address, but he is not sure. Can you confirm?

Is "Hello" stored in an instance variable of the class String?

Comment: Facetiously, it's because Java is kludged in this respect. Consider it an exception that the language makes. Cf C++ where there is no such special treatment extended to 'standard' objects. I'm glad you're asking such questions. Have an upvote!

Comment: Not a duplicate per se, because the proposed duplicate is about c#

Comment: @Ousmane That's not a Java question

Comment: Note: "Has a literal form" != "is a primitive type"

Comment: Try to do this int i = null

Comment: “_Equivalent to an address_”! The concept of an address is more or less foreign to the Java Language Specification (SE 8 Edition): I only see it (in this sense) under **Semantics of `final` fields**. A string literal is simply an expression of type `String`, as pointed out (with a reference) in T.J. Crowder’s answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ...as if `String` were a primitive?

As [Jon points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171690/why-in-java-we-can-use-the-string-class-as-if-it-were-a-primitive#comment73417347_43171690), "has a literal form" != "is a primitive type." :-) Strings have a literal form in Java because [the spec defines one for them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). `String` is still an object type.

Some languages have other object types that also have literal forms (JavaScript, for instance, has literal forms for regular expressions, arrays, and non-array objects *[its literal form for strings does actually define what it calls a string primitive rather than string object — JavaScript has both primitive and object versions of strings]*). I *think* strings are the only one in Java (other than `null`, which is the literal for "no object"), although of course there are array initializers, which are *similar* but not quite the same as literals.

Comment: Due to autoboxing, other literal forms may appear as evaluating to object instances as well: `Boolean b = true;` or `Number n = 42;`…

Comment: @Holger: The literal, though, results in a primitive; the boxing happens separately. (Which you know, but flagging it for lurkers.)

Comment: Now that I had a second thought: **Class Literals**. Since Java 1.1, there are class literals. `Class<?> cl = Long.class;` These definitely qualify, even if the JLS authors forgot naming them in the [Literals section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10). They are there in [their own section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)…

Comment: @Holger Good one. I don't know why those feel different to me than normal literals. They do, but I can't immediately think of a good reason...

Answer (score 13):

The fact that you can use a **literal** expression doesn't mean that the expression results in a primitive type! That is simply a **misconception** on your end.

You see:

```
 Integer[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

is also a literal (well, "almost"; as you can only use it for such kind of array init statements); but it is not a primitive type!

And to ask the **why** part in your question: chances are - simply for convenience. When Java was created, it was meant to be "better" than the C and C++ of those days. And guess what: dealing with strings was pretty annoying and error prone in those languages.

In that sense: introducing string literals could be seen as [unique selling point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition) to differentiate Java from its competition!

Answer (score 8):

Other answers are pretty good. Some specific points:

> I asked this to my teacher and he replied that it is because what is in quotes is equivalent to an address, but he is not sure. Can you confirm?

Yes. He is right. As others have pointed out, a string literal, i.e. a valid Unicode character sequence enclosed inside a pair of "s is recognized by the Java Language Specification. When the Java compiler (the `javac` program) encounters such a literal (e.g. `"Hello"`) in your Java source file, it takes it *literally* and places it in a specific section inside the compiled [class file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html). This section is called the *runtime constant pool*. It then creates a particular instruction called `ldc` that it places in the class file where the *compiled* code for your initialization is stored. For instance, the body of the `main` method in the following Java source code:

```
public class StringAsPrimitive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello";
    }
}
```

gets compiled to:

```
     0: ldc           #2                  // String Hello
     2: astore_1
     3: return
```

(There is no magic here. Just compile your code using `javac` program and view the class file using the `javap` program. You can even see the contents of the .class file using a hex viewer and you will see the String `Hello` *literally*).

This code is then *interpreted* by the JVM when you ask the `java` program to *run* this class file.

The `ldc` instruction to the JVM is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc). This is what the JVM then does when it interprets `#2` which is a reference to the actual location where the literal string `"Hello"` is stored in the computer's memory (RAM):

> Otherwise, if the run-time constant pool entry is a reference to an
>   instance of class String representing a string literal (§5.1), then a
>   reference to that instance, value, is pushed onto the operand stack.

So, what your teacher said turns out to be right, although we don't say it quite that way. In Java, there are two kinds of types: primitive and *reference*. So, it would be more appropriate to say that the value of the String literal is a reference (and not address).

> Is "Hello" stored in an instance variable of the class String?

No. The String variable initialized to a String literal could be anything, a `static` or class variable, an instance variable or a local variable (my code above). It is stored in the class file: `StringAsPrimitive.class` and later it is available to the JVM in a particular memory location. This happens when the JVM *loads* the class.

Answer (score 1):

All literals are not primitives.

From [JLS 3.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

> 3.10. Literals
>
> A literal is the source code representation of a value of a primitive
> type (§4.2), the String type (§4.3.3), or the null type (§4.1).
>
> Literal:
>
> IntegerLiteral
>
> FloatingPointLiteral
>
> BooleanLiteral
>
> CharacterLiteral
>
> StringLiteral
>
> NullLiteral

So `String` literals are not primitives but objects.

The JLS references it and you can also deduce it because `String` instances have methods while primitive cannot have methods.

String literals (`String myString = "Hello"`) have very likely been introduced by the language to ease the declaration of String that is a type as common as primitive types such as `int` or `boolean`.
Imagine a `String` concatenation such as :

```
new String("hello ") + new String (nameInput) + new String (" and welcome!");
```

This is clearly more verbose, less readable and therefore more error prone than :

```
 "hello " + nameInput +" and welcome!";
```

Comment: Thank you! But is the string "Hello" stored into an istance variable of the class String?

Comment: @AlessandroF, no, the string "Hello" is stored in the so-called "runtime constant pool" (a specific location) inside the `.class` file of the Java source file where you have defined the variable like: `String myString = "Hello"`.

Comment: it's still stored as a variable of class String though

Comment: @Walfrat, Nothing is ever stored _as_ a variable.  A variable is a _place_ where a value can be stored, but it's not the only place.  When you see `1` or `"hello"` in a program, those are _constant_ expressions---expressions whose values are compiled in to the program's byte-code.  The value of the expression, `1` is of course a primitive, `int` value.  The value of `"hello"` is a reference to an instance of the `String` class that is created when the class file is loaded.  Either value can be _assigned_ to a variable, or it can be used directly, without any variable being involved.

Comment: @jameslarge I know, I don't think that AlessandroF who asked this was looking for that level of detail.

Comment: @davidxx Primitives types are immutable by definition see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037082/are-java-primitives-immutable

Comment: @Walfrat: you don’t need to dive deep into it; you may write `System.out.println("hello");` or `System.out.println(42);` without having a variable being involved. And you may declare a variable `String v="hello";` or `int v=42;`, if you wish, still, there is no difference between strings or primitive types in this regard. That’s basically, what @james large said, you can assign a value to a variable. Or you use the value without assigning it to a variable…

Comment: @Holger as I said earlier, I know