# Is it better use use a char array or string if the word that is stored will change often?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I know that `String` is immutable so if you change a string it will make a separate string so I thought that a `char` array might be a better option. I looked up if `char` is immutable and a lot of people say it is and some people say it is just the wrapper class that is immutable. I want to know if `char` is immutable and if using a `char` array is a better option than using a String if the word that is stored will change often

Comment: Use StringBuffer?

Comment: Use a String. Make your code robust and readable instead of trying to make it faster for no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

char is immutable because it is a primitive. Check out this answer: [Are Java primitives immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037082/are-java-primitives-immutable)

Regardless, arrays are mutable. You can change the value of the char array by changing the values in the array.

Is using a char array more efficient? theoretically yes, however you will be giving up a lot of the functionality given by using String. This will force you to implement stuff yourself, which will probably be less efficient than just using String.

My advice, start with String, if your whole application performance is dependant on this, you can start thinking of other solutions.

Don't solve problems you do not have :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Java all primitive types are mutable by default and immutable if and only if they are defined with the `final` modifier. Using a `char` array as a mutable alternative to `String` is wrong. Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: final and mutability are orthogonal concepts. Is a final String immutable? Read the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037082/are-java-primitives-immutable

Comment: `String` is not primitive, so your comment has no sense in discussion of my answer. Read the original question and my answer to it again.

Comment: My point is that final does not make something immutable. You are confusing immutability with final. Please read https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-vs-immutability-java/amp/

Comment: I'm not confusing anything. @Ammawn has asked two questions: 1) "I want to know if `char` is immutable"; 2) "...  if using a `char` array is a better option than using a `String` if the word that is stored will change often". Also read my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037082/are-java-primitives-immutable regarding mutability of primitive types in Java.